# How do I cancel a FileStream.ReadAsync( ... ) Request?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, filestream, cancellationtokensource

Given the following :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CancelAsyncFileReadFailure {
    class Program {
        static void Main( string[ ] args ) {
            Console.WriteLine( Foo( ).Result );
            Console.ReadLine( );
        }

public static async Task<TaskStatus> Foo( ) {
    byte[] bar = new byte[192000]; //Some arbitrarily significant number...
    using ( FileStream FS = new FileSTream( @"Path/To/WarAndPeace.txt", FileMode.Open ) ){
        CancellationTokenSource CTS = new CancellationTokenSource( );       
        Task T = FS.ReadAsync( bar, 0, 192000, CTS.Token );
        CTS.Cancel( );      
        await T;
        return T.Status;
    }
}
```

`T` will *always* finish and return `RanToCompletion`.

My use case is somewhat more complex in that I am reading from a device which may be opened or closed at any time (and as such am not reading directly from a file, but from a safe file handle; however the results are the same in both this case and my actual use case).

I want to interrupt (cancel) FileStream.ReadToAsync( ).

How can I go about doing that in such a way that it will stop reading where it is at and cancel right away?

Comment: `CancellationTokenSource` needs to be setup outside the function, [check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155759.aspx)

Comment: @balexandre : Please elaborate. Do you mean that I need to declare it outside the function (as a class-based variable), or that I need to call `CancellationTokenSource.Token.Register( ( ) => { } )` with something?

Comment: I do not see any incorrect usage of `CancellationTokenSource` here.

Comment: Okay - I see what they are doing in there but that's *exactly* what I am doing here. They are calling `await client.GetAsync("Some_URL", SomeCancellationTokenSource.Token)`. That's EXACTLY what I am doing in my code and it's not working. The cancellation call is made as soon as the task is assigned to the variable and it's not working.

Comment: are you seeing the same link as I am? the task does not create the object The cancellation happens outside... you initialize the program, you initialize the object and where you want to cancel just invoke it.

Comment: @balexandre to use your terminology, "the task" is `ReadAsync`, and "outside" is his code.

Comment: @balexandre, this is a perfectly valid example of `CancellationTokenSource ` usage. The cancellation occurs asynchronously, while the task is in flight. If anything this is a pretty well-constructed test.

Comment: why not checking if the task was canceled with `if (CTS.IsCancellationRequested) return TaskStatus.Canceled;` as @Cory mentioned well, it will not work with reading from file

Comment: @balexandre : I know; that's why I am going with something similar. The method in question has to sit in a loop, read from the stream, respond to the data it finds, and read from the stream again, over and over. Now it reads from the stream and then tosses the data if the cancellation has been requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, better answer here.

You need to open the file with `FileOptions.Asynchronous`. If you don't, `FileStream` will not implement true cancellation and will only return a cancelled `Task` if the token was cancelled at the time of calling `ReadAsync`.

Comment: Close but no cigar. That's what I originally thought (as the constructor used in the question produces a `FileStream` with `IsAsync = false`), but the behaviour remains exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks though. Unfortunately when opening with a `SafeFileHandle`, there is no overload that allows me to pass `FileOptions.Asynchronous`...

Comment: @Will, there is a `FileStream` constructor taking an `isAsync` parameter that will do the same thing.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy My previous answer was correct, but this one is too -- looking at the `ReadAsync` code, it completely bypasses any attempt at cancellation if the stream is not opened async.

Comment: I tried setting that to true but it exploded :

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Handle does not support asynchronous operations. The parameters to the FileStream constructor may need to be changed to indicate that the handle was opened synchronously (that is, it was not opened for overlapped I/O).`

Comment: How are you opening your `SafeFileHandle`? Setting async requires a file handle that can be added to an I/O Completion Port.

Comment: `[DllImport( "kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto )]
  private static extern SafeFileHandle` - this is for Device I/O, not File I/O (I figured that they were similar enough that this example would accurately explain my problem).

Comment: @Will, this doesn't actually work with files opened with a path (i.e. `new FileStream(@"Path/To/WarAndPeace.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 2048, FileOptions.Asynchronous)`), for reasons that I've already talked about, so don't hold your breath.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy : I know. I'm not actually opening a text file - that was just for a MCV example; what I am opening is a device for I/O.

Comment: Essentially, you need to pass `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` to `CreateFile` or whatever you're using. If that's not supported, you're out of luck.

Comment: Seems not working on Linux. At least when reading `/dev/input/eventX`.

Comment: @TN. please [file an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues) with a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Cancellation is best-effort -- it only happens if an operation is actually able to be cancelled.

Two cases I can think of here are either it hit the filesystem cache, in which case the read could be completed immediately and synchronously, or that the I/O request was already sent to the disk.

Comment: So in short - FileStream.ReadAsync( ) does not actually implement Cancellation, at least in my use case. *awesome*.

Answer (score 1):

Will, Cory's previous answer was actually right on the money. Cancellation needs to occur when it's *safe* for it to happen. In the case of a stream read the only such point is *before* the read actually starts. If a stream read request is cancelled in-flight, what do you expect the stream's `Position` to be when the cancelled task actually completes? It could be fine to roll it back in the case of `FileStream`, but what about streams that are forward-only? What if you want to schedule another `ReadAsync` immediately after the previous task transitions to Canceled state? You'd get a dropped data chunk and a horrible corruption. This actually seems like a sensible design on Microsoft's part. Make your buffer size smaller and call `ReadAsync` in a loop - then you'll get desired cancellation semantics.

Comment: Thanks. That would work if I was reading some huge amount of data but unfortunately what I'm reading in is actually quite small - 10 bytes at most, and it's device I/O so it's... well, it's pretty complicated. I was able to conceive a reasonable workaround though, in which if the cancellation request was made while the read was occurring, the result will just be ignored...

Comment: Yeah, if "cancel and abandon" is a viable approach, the general advice given in these cases applies: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx